# Is there any way to create triggers and stored procedures in an RDS MySQL instance at create time when creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

By default, RDS MySQL instances, created during Elastic Beanstalk environment creation, do not allow the creation of triggers, functions, and stored procedures because the master user does not have SUPER privilege, binary logging is enabled, and `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is false. So any scripts that attempt this in container_commands will fail.

This can be worked around *after* instantiation by changing to a non-default DB parameter group with `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1`. See [this video](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/) for an explanation of how to do it interactively. However, it seems you cannot associate a new instance with a non-default parameter group at creation time. So, you are forced to instantiate without triggers and stored procs, modify the instance to use the non-default parameter group, reboot the instance, and only then can you run scripts to create triggers and stored procs.

To make matters worse, you can’t even allow your container_commands that create the triggers to run because that causes the instantiation to fail and you don’t get a working instance to which you could apply the manual intervention described.  So you need your container_commands to be commented out during creation, then re-enabled during a subsequent post-reboot ‘eb deploy’. In this scenario, you cannot automate the creation of environments that require DDL creating triggers, functions, or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was written with a specific MySQL parameter in mind, but it applies to any situation where a non-default DB Parameter Group is needed. After some discussion with AWS tech support, you *can* associate a non-default DB Parameter Group to RDS instances during environment creation. I'll suggest the documentation could be better ;-)

This example is specific to MySQL 8.0 (`mysql8.0`), but it should be apparent what you'll change for your particular situation.

Add the following to a file in .ebextensions/

```
Resources:
  customdbparametergroup:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup'
    Properties:
      Description: "DB parameter group for Beanstalk RDS instance which enables functions, procedures, and triggers"
      Family: "mysql8.0"
      Parameters:
        "log_bin_trust_function_creators" : 1

  AWSEBRDSDatabase:
      Properties:
        DBParameterGroupName:
          Ref: customdbparametergroup
```

Of course, if you already have a configuration file with a `Resources:` section, you will just add the parameter group resource and the `AWSEBRDSDatabase` key. When you examine the created instance, the parameter group name will be mangled in the usual way. You *must* declare the parameter group as a resource in the configuration i.e. you cannot specify the name of an existing parameter group.